# Centered CheckBox in TableView JavaFX

Tags: checkbox, tableview, javafx-2, centering

I find a problem when dealing with tableview that need a centered checkbox column. I am able to create a column with checkbox. I also want to set property in my model according to that checkbox value. I did it with the following code:

```
isCanceledCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TransactionModel,CheckBox>,ObservableValue<CheckBox>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<CheckBox> call(final CellDataFeatures<TransactionModel, CheckBox> p) {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                        p.getValue().setIsCanceled(t1.booleanValue());
                    }
                }
                        );
                canceledCB.add(cb);
                return new SimpleObjectProperty(cb);
            }
```

The problem with the code above is, the checkboxes appear with left alignment. I want to make it centered, but I also want to keep the changed event of the checkbox to change my model property ( p.getValue().setIsCanceled(t1.booleanValue()); ).

I really appreciate help from you guys.

Regards,
Chrisma Andhika

Comment: I don't know if it is possible and haven't tried it myself but is there a way to wrap the checkbox in a HBox before adding to the cell? Again, just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX Ensemble (javafx sample) has the perfect code that you are trying to use. Plus they have given a better way of using a `CheckBox` in a `TableView`.

The point is to extent `TableCell` used by the `TableView` control. For creating a `CheckBox` column following should be created and used:

```
//CheckBoxTableCell for creating a CheckBox in a table cell
public static class CheckBoxTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {
    private final CheckBox checkBox;
    private ObservableValue<T> ov;

    public CheckBoxTableCell() {
        this.checkBox = new CheckBox();
        this.checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setGraphic(checkBox);
    } 

    @Override public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(checkBox);
            if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {
                checkBox.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional((BooleanProperty) ov);
            }
            ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
            if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {
                checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional((BooleanProperty) ov);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)` will set your control in the center of the cell.